# Saving the order of items

Tags: python, html, django

My model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

My template:

```
{% for c in categories %}
    {{ c }} -- <input type="text" name="order[{{ c.id }}]" value="{{ c.order }}">
    Submit Button
{% endfor %}
```

My view:

```
def category_order(request):
    print request.POST
    print request.POST.getlist('order[]')
```

Output:

```
<QueryDict: {u'order[3]': [u'1'], u'order[1]': [u'1'], u'order[5]': [u'2'], u'order[4]': [u'33'], u'order[2]': [u'2'], u'order[6]': [u'3'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'4XjehEwMdNK032342JkYJvBJabunKB'], u'order-btn': [u'order']}>
[]
```

So my question is how can I loop over every order[N] and get the category ID and its new order value to save it to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dict comprehension:

```
orders = {name.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]: request.POST[name]
          for name in request.POST if name.startswith('order[')}
# `orders` is not a dictionary maps `id`s to `order`s.
# Do something with `orders`.
```

Or using simple for loop:

```
for name in request.POST:
    if not name.startswith('order['): continue
    id_ = name.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
    order = request.POST[name]
    # Do something with `id_`, `order`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at having ordered objects, there is a library, [django-ordered-model](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model) , that can take care of that. That includes a good, drag-and-drop admin view. For example:

```
from django.db import models
from ordered_model.models import OrderedModel

class Category(OrderedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta(OrderedModel.Meta):
        pass
```